# Update dictionary value in array of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this array of dictionaries in Python 2.7

```
[{'t': 1, 'l': 'cd', 'e': 'extra'}, {'t': 2, 'l': 'ab'}, {'t': 3, 'l': 'abc'}, {'t': 4, 'l': 'ab'}]
```

How do I update it to append a counter on duplicate 'l' value so that the result would look like the following?

```
[{'t': 1, 'l': 'cd', 'e': 'extra'}, {'t': 2, 'l': 'ab_1'}, {'t': 3, 'l': 'abc'}, {'t': 4, 'l': 'ab_2'}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I don't think there is a one liner solution, that's someone can just give you.

Comment: Yes, I did. I was looking for a pythonic solution using generator similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202444/python-how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-list-and-update-these-duplicate-items-by-re. But, I can't figure out how to append the rest of dict keys that don't get modified.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to identify what's to be updated,

```
a[-1]['l'] += '_2'
```

might suffice.  But if that's not what you want, you'd better be **much** more specific on how you plan to tag exactly what's to be updated!-)

Answer (score 0):

A fairly straightforward solution would be to first, convert the list of dictionaries into a dictionary of lists, based on values of 'l'.  Then, you can convert it back to the original shape adding suffix to a multi-list element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
a_list = [{'t': 1, 'l': 'cd'}, {'t': 2, 'l': 'ab'}, {'t': 3, 'l': 'abc'}, {'t': 4, 'l': 'ab'}]

# keep 'l' values, so that we can calculate how many of them we have
list_of_values = []

out_list = []

# iterate through each dict in the input list 
# to create out_list with appended counter on duplicate 'l' values
for d in a_list:
    l_value, t_value = d['l'], d['t']         

    list_of_values.append(l_value)

    l_count = list_of_values.count(l_value)

    if l_count > 1:
    # add new dict to out_list, so that 'l' values contain number 
    # of times they appear in a_list. t value is same as it was.            
    #out_list.append({'t': t_value, 'l':"{}_{}".format(l_value, l_count)})
        out_list.append({'t': t_value, 'l':"{}_{}".format(l_value, l_count)})
    else:
        out_list.append(d)


print(out_list)
```

Result is:

```
[{'l': 'cd', 't': 1}, {'l': 'ab', 't': 2}, {'l': 'abc', 't': 3}, {'l': 'ab_2', 't': 4}]
```

Comment: How do I prevent a suffix from being added to the non duplicate 'l'?

Comment: I just updated the question. Is there an easy way to generalized the solution where the dict could have optional key val pair?