# Python: Rename duplicates in list with progressive numbers without sorting list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, rename

Given a list like this:

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
```

I would like to rename the duplicates by appending a number to get the following result:

```
mylist = ["name1", "state", "name2", "city", "name3", "zip1", "zip2"]
```

I do not want to change the order of the original list.  The solutions suggested for this [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17202444/259538) sorts the list, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how I would do it. EDIT: I wrote this into a more generalized utility function since people seem to like this answer.

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
check = ["name1", "state", "name2", "city", "name3", "zip1", "zip2"]
copy = mylist[:]  # so we will only mutate the copy in case of failure

from collections import Counter # Counter counts the number of occurrences of each item
from itertools import tee, count

def uniquify(seq, suffs = count(1)):
    """Make all the items unique by adding a suffix (1, 2, etc).

    `seq` is mutable sequence of strings.
    `suffs` is an optional alternative suffix iterable.
    """
    not_unique = [k for k,v in Counter(seq).items() if v>1] # so we have: ['name', 'zip']
    # suffix generator dict - e.g., {'name': <my_gen>, 'zip': <my_gen>}
    suff_gens = dict(zip(not_unique, tee(suffs, len(not_unique))))  
    for idx,s in enumerate(seq):
        try:
            suffix = str(next(suff_gens[s]))
        except KeyError:
            # s was unique
            continue
        else:
            seq[idx] += suffix

uniquify(copy)
assert copy==check  # raise an error if we failed
mylist = copy  # success
```

If you wanted to append an underscore before each count, you could do something like this:

```
>>> mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
>>> uniquify(mylist, (f'_{x!s}' for x in range(1, 100)))
>>> mylist
['name_1', 'state', 'name_2', 'city', 'name_3', 'zip_1', 'zip_2']
```

...or if you wanted to use letters instead:

```
>>> mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
>>> import string
>>> uniquify(mylist, (f'_{x!s}' for x in string.ascii_lowercase))
>>> mylist
['name_a', 'state', 'name_b', 'city', 'name_c', 'zip_a', 'zip_b']
```

NOTE: this is not the fastest possible algorithm; for that, refer to [the answer by ronakg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651843/2437514). The advantage of the function above is it is easy to understand and read, and you're not going to see much of a performance difference unless you have an extremely large list.

EDIT: Here is my original answer in a one-liner, however the order is not preserved and it uses the `.index` method, which is extremely suboptimal (as explained in [the answer by DTing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651012/2437514)). See [the answer by queezz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454407/2437514) for a nice 'two-liner' that preserves order.

```
[s + str(suffix) if num>1 else s for s,num in Counter(mylist).items() for suffix in range(1, num+1)]
# Produces: ['zip1', 'zip2', 'city', 'state', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

Comment: This is my favorite suggestion, as it is compact and easy to read.  THANKS!

Answer (score 26):

My solution with `map` and `lambda`:

```
print map(lambda x: x[1] + str(mylist[:x[0]].count(x[1]) + 1) if mylist.count(x[1]) > 1 else x[1], enumerate(mylist))
```

More traditional form

```
newlist = []
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    totalcount = mylist.count(v)
    count = mylist[:i].count(v)
    newlist.append(v + str(count + 1) if totalcount > 1 else v)
```

And last one

```
[v + str(mylist[:i].count(v) + 1) if mylist.count(v) > 1 else v for i, v in enumerate(mylist)]
```

Comment: The lambda 1 liner is a bit complicated, but your second suggestion is nice.  Thanks!

Comment: Added one liner similar to Rick Teachey solution but with order preserving

Comment: this solution actually is pricey since it takes O(n^2)

Comment: thanks! I really admire how smart it is to make the list item unique based on the count of the list slice up to [:i] (in the last list comprehension solution), my sincere compliments!!!

Answer (score 11):

Any method where `count` is called on each element is going to result in `O(n^2)` since `count` is `O(n)`. You can do something like this:

```
# not modifying original list
from collections import Counter

mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
counts = {k:v for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v > 1}
newlist = mylist[:]

for i in reversed(range(len(mylist))):
    item = mylist[i]
    if item in counts and counts[item]:
        newlist[i] += str(counts[item])
        counts[item]-=1
print(newlist)

# ['name1', 'state', 'name2', 'city', 'name3', 'zip1', 'zip2']
```

---

```
# modifying original list
from collections import Counter

mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
counts = {k:v for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v > 1}      

for i in reversed(range(len(mylist))):
    item = mylist[i]
    if item in counts and counts[item]:
        mylist[i] += str(counts[item])
        counts[item]-=1
print(mylist)

# ['name1', 'state', 'name2', 'city', 'name3', 'zip1', 'zip2']
```

This should be `O(n)`.

## Other provided answers:

**`mylist.index(s)` per element causes `O(n^2)`**

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(mylist)
for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
        for suffix in range(1, num + 1):
            mylist[mylist.index(s)] = s + str(suffix)
```

---

**`count(x[1])` per element causes `O(n^2)`**
It is also used multiple times per element along with list slicing.

```
print map(lambda x: x[1] + str(mylist[:x[0]].count(x[1]) + 1) if mylist.count(x[1]) > 1 else x[1], enumerate(mylist))
```

### Benchmarks:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/dting/c28fb161de7b6287491b

Comment: I changed my answer to do away with `.index` per your suggestions. Much better.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a very simple `O(n)` solution. Simply walk the list storing the index of element in the list. If we've seen this element before, use the stored data earlier to append the occurrence value.

This approach solves the problem with just creating one more dictionary for look-back. Avoids doing look-ahead so that we don't create temporary list slices.

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name"]

dups = {}

for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
    if val not in dups:
        # Store index of first occurrence and occurrence value
        dups[val] = [i, 1]
    else:
        # Special case for first occurrence
        if dups[val][1] == 1:
            mylist[dups[val][0]] += str(dups[val][1])

        # Increment occurrence value, index value doesn't matter anymore
        dups[val][1] += 1

        # Use stored occurrence value
        mylist[i] += str(dups[val][1])

print mylist

# ['name1', 'state', 'name2', 'city1', 'city2', 'name3', 'zip1', 'zip2', 'name4']
```

Comment: This is nice but have you ever seen `collections.Counter`? Use that and you don't have to implement your own counting algorithm.

Comment: Yes I know about `collections.Counter` :). I just wanted to post a solution that's more efficient. This solution does just one pass of the list.

Answer (score 4):

A list comprehension version of the Rick Teachey [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651963/3730379), "two-liner":

```
from collections import Counter

m = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]

d = {a:list(range(1, b+1)) if b>1 else '' for a,b in Counter(m).items()}
[i+str(d[i].pop(0)) if len(d[i]) else i for i in m]
#['name1', 'state', 'name2', 'city', 'name3', 'zip1', 'zip2']
```

Comment: very nice answer, but you needed to do range(1,b+1) to get the desired suffixes.

Comment: Sure, range(1,b+1). Must've missed the indexing while using some old variable in the notebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hashtable to solve this problem. Define a dictionary d. key is the string and value is (first_time_index_in_the_list, times_of_appearance). Everytime when you see a word, just check the dictionary, and if the value is 2, use first_time_index_in_the_list to append '1' to the first element, and append times_of_appearance to current element. If greater than 2, just append times_of_appearance to current element.

Comment: Would be nice with an example code, it's faster for the eye to realize the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Less fancy stuff.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip"]
finalList = []
dictCount = defaultdict(int)
anotherDict = defaultdict(int)
for t in mylist:
   anotherDict[t] += 1
for m in mylist:
   dictCount[m] += 1
   if anotherDict[m] > 1:
       finalList.append(str(m)+str(dictCount[m]))
   else:
       finalList.append(m)
print finalList
```

Answer (score 1):

**Beware of updated values that already exist in the original list**

If the starting list already includes an item `"name2"` ...

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name2"]
```

...then `mylist[2]` shouldn't be updated to `"name2"` when the function runs, otherwise a new duplicate will be created; instead, the function should jump to the next available item name `"name3"` .

```
mylist_updated = ['name1', 'state', 'name3', 'city', 'name4', 'zip1', 'zip2', 'name2']
```

Here's an alternate solution (can probably be shortened and optimized) which includes a recursive function that checks for these existing items in the original list.

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name2"]

def fix_dups(mylist, sep='', start=1, update_first=True):
    mylist_dups = {}
    #build dictionary containing val: [occurrences, suffix]
    for val in mylist:
        if val not in mylist_dups:
            mylist_dups[val] = [1, start - 1]
        else:
            mylist_dups[val][0] += 1
            
    #define function to update duplicate values with suffix, check if updated value already exists
    def update_val(val, num):
        temp_val = sep.join([str(x) for x in [val, num]])
        if temp_val not in mylist_dups:
            return temp_val, num
        else:
            num += 1
            return update_val(val, num)        
    
    #update list
    for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
        if mylist_dups[val][0] > 1:
            mylist_dups[val][1] += 1  
            if update_first or mylist_dups[val][1] > start:
                new_val, mylist_dups[val][1] = update_val(val, mylist_dups[val][1])
                mylist[i] = new_val

    return mylist
                
mylist_updated = fix_dups(mylist, sep='', start=1, update_first=True)
print(mylist_updated)
#['name1', 'state', 'name3', 'city', 'name4', 'zip1', 'zip2', 'name2']
```

In case you don't want to change the first occurrence.

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city", "name", "zip", "zip", "name_2"]
             
mylist_updated = fix_dups(mylist, sep='_', start=0, update_first=False)
print(mylist_updated)
#['name', 'state', 'name_1', 'city', 'name_3', 'zip', 'zip_1', 'name_2']
```